# Loading XML contents into Php (Joomla)

Tags: php, xml, joomla

I am trying to load the contents of an XML-file into a custom php code module in Joomla 2.5.

My XML is in the root folder "/country-info" and the name of my XML file is "country-info.xml".

The contents of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<germany>
<citizens>81,8 Mio.</citizens>
</germany>
```

and this is one of the php codes i found:

```
<?php
   $completeurl ="country-info/country-info.xml";
   $xml = simplexml_load_file($completeurl);
   $citizens = $xml->germany->citizens;

    echo $citizens;

?>
```

edit - new code:

```
<?php
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<germany-citizens>81,8 Mio.</citizens>
';
    $catid = JRequest::getInt('id');
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $sql = "SELECT alias FROM #__categories WHERE id = ".intval($catid);
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $displayarea = $db->loadResult();
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $citizens = $xml-> {$displayarea . '-citizens'};
    echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;Citizens:&nbsp;' . $citizens . '&nbsp;|&nbsp;';
?>
```

Comment: So... What's the problem?

Comment: Hi David,The problem is that the contents of the xml file are not shown and i am not sure if the code and path are correct.

Comment: Alright. I'll test it. Hold on.

Comment: This worked for me: http://viper-7.com/PARSbJ -- If it doesn't work for you, you may not have the SimpleXML extension installed.

Comment: I just checked and simplephp is being loaded und enabled (xampp and vserver). Doesnt work on Xampp and doesnt work on my vserver. Any ideas?

Comment: Weird. `var_dump(extension_loaded('simplexml'));` and `var_dump($xml);`

Comment: that is what i get now: bool(true) object(SimpleXMLElement)#281 (3) { ["citizens"]=> string(9) "81,8 Mio." ["voters"]=> string(7) "44 Mio." ["turnout"]=> string(6) "70.78%" }

Comment: Yeah, it's all there :S Did you try my example?

Comment: Yes thanks. Its working great but the file isnt external, thats what i wanted to achive.

Comment: Okay, then you'll have to point your `simplexml_load_file` to the correct file path, that's all.

Comment: How can i set your code to use <germany> </germany> as category? I want it to use a variable. My modified version extracts the alias from the joomla base automatically. Now i want the data only extracted from a specific category in the xml. ex. the german categorys alias is "germany", so "citizens" will only get extracted from the "germany" that matches the alias.

Comment: I added the current code above

Answer (score 0):

It might be the path being incorrect. I have defined the root of your site so you can go on from there.

```
<?php
   $completeurl = JURI::root() . "country-info/country-info.xml";
   $xml = simplexml_load_file($completeurl);
   $citizens = $xml->germany->citizens;

    echo $citizens;
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Lodder, thanks alot. I already tried that and unfortunately its not working :(